# Java program doesn't loop round the while loop - goes straight to an if statement

Tags: java

I am creating a rock, paper, scissors game to try out my Java skills. In my code I have a while loop that loops round until the winner has either won or lost the amount of rounds that they entered. This part does not work. It goes straight to the logic statement, which outside of the while loop even though it hasn't completed that loop.

code:

```
package rps_game;
// Rock, Paper, Scissors game
//

import java.util.*;

public class rock_paper_scissors {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner lineInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        String choices[] = { "rock", "paper", "scissors" };

        int winRounds = 0;
        boolean running = true;

        int rounds = 0;
        int wins = 0;
        int loses = 0;

        String yourChoice = "";
        String compChoice = "";
        while (running = true) { // main loop

            try {
                System.out
                        .println("Enter the amount of rounds you want to play: ");
                rounds = input.nextInt(); // gets input
                winRounds = (rounds / 2) + 1;
                System.out.println("You are playing best of " + winRounds
                        + " out of " + rounds);

                //running = false; // breaks off from loop

                while (wins < winRounds && loses < winRounds) { // this while loop
                    System.out.println("Enter either Rock, Paper or Scissors: ");

                    yourChoice = lineInput.nextLine();
                    yourChoice= yourChoice.toLowerCase();
                    if (Arrays.asList(choices).contains(yourChoice)) { // what use entered
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("You did not enter either Rock, Paper or Scissors.");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }

                    compChoice = choices[rand.nextInt(choices.length)];
                    System.out.println("ROCK.. PAPER.. SCISSORS!");
                    System.out.println("You entered: " + yourChoice + " and the computer entered: " + compChoice);

                    if (yourChoice.equals(compChoice)){
                        System.out.println("\nIt's a draw!");
                    }else if(yourChoice.equals("rock") && compChoice.equals("paper")){
                        System.out.println("\nYou lose!");
                        loses++;
                    }else if(yourChoice.equals("paper") && compChoice.equals("rock")){
                        System.out.println("\nYou win!");
                        wins++;
                    }else if(yourChoice.equals("scissors") && compChoice.equals("paper")){
                        System.out.println("\nYou win!");
                        wins++;
                    }else if(yourChoice.equals("paper") && compChoice.equals("Scissors")){
                        System.out.println("\nYou lose!");
                        loses++;
                    }else if(yourChoice.equals("rock") && compChoice.equals("scissors")){
                        System.out.println("\nYou win!");
                        wins++;
                    }else if(yourChoice.equals("scissors") && compChoice.equals("rock")){
                        System.out.println("\nYou lose!");
                        loses++;
                    }else{
                        break;
                    }

                }
                System.out.println("\nGAME FINISHED!");

                if (wins > loses){
                    System.out.println("\nYOU WIN THE GAME!!");
                }else if(wins < loses){
                    System.out.println("\nYOU LOST THE GAME!! :( ");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("It's a draw!!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) { // if error pops up
                System.out.println("You DID NOT enter a WHOLE NUMBER.");
                break;
            }

        }

        input.close();
        lineInput.close();
    }
}
```

Why isn't it looping like it is supposed to? I really can't figure this out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your break statement

```
if (Arrays.asList(choices).contains(yourChoice)) { // what use entered
    break;
}
```

`break` causes you to exit the loop, and I don't think that you want to exit the loop when you've chosen a correct input.

---

in-fact since you also have that `System.exit` command inside the `else` block, none of your inner while loop will execute after these two lines, no matter what.

```
if (Arrays.asList(choices).contains(yourChoice)) { // what use entered
    break;
} else {
    System.out.println("You did not enter either Rock, Paper or Scissors.");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

I would recommend getting rid of the `break` statement, and changing `System.exit(0);` to `continue`, which will just skip to the next iteration of the loop.  If you do this, you might also be able to re-work the if-logic since there is only 1 condition.

Comment: @KubaSpatny yes.  Breaking out of the inner while is the problem that the OP described

Comment: Yeah sorry I was looking at it on my phone and thought the `if`s were after the outer while..

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. I haven't had that much experience with while loops in Java and some other languages. But thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`while (running = true)` should be `while (running == true)`

Edit: look into [Yoda Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) as a way to avoid doing this.

Comment: Or just have `while(running)`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Like @David Ehrmann said, you need to change your `running = true` to `running == true` or just `while(running)`, your logic in this if statement is wrong:

```
if (Arrays.asList(choices).contains(yourChoice)) { // what use entered
   break;
} else {
   System.out.println("You did not enter either Rock, Paper or Scissors.");
   System.exit(0);
}
```

You don't want to `break` when you have entered in the correct input. A proper if statement should be:

```
if (!(Arrays.asList(choices).contains(yourChoice))) 
{
     System.out.println("You did not enter either Rock, Paper, or Scissors.");
     running = false;  
     break;
}
else
{
   // the rest of the playing code
}
```

This assumes that you want to gracefully exit. It should print "It's a draw." and cleanup any resources this way... if that's what you want.

Comment: Good answer, doing this would be better than using `break;`